# Stuck on showing a property of $H$ as a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$. Then it has operators $E, F, H$ such that $HE - EH = 2E, HF - FH = -2F, EF - FE = H$. Let $\bar{V}(\lambda)$ represent the generalized eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$ for some linear map.

I can show the following facts. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $H$ with maximal real part, then $E$ restricted to $\bar{V}(\lambda)$ is the zero map. If $v \in \ker E$ is non-zero, then $E^k F^k v = P_k(H) v$, where $P_k(H) = k! H (H - 1) \cdots (H - (k - 1))$. If $v \in \bar{V}(\lambda)$ of $H$ for any choice of $\lambda$, then there exists a $N > 0$ such that $F^N v = 0$.

I am next asked to show that $H$ is diagonalizable on $\bar{V}(\lambda)$ (of $H$) by utilizing the fact that $P_k$ does not have repeated roots and computing $E^N F^N v$, where $N$ is picked as defined previously. In particular, I can show that if $v \in \bar{V}(\lambda)$ is non-zero and $(H - a_1) \cdots (H - a_n) v = 0$ and the $a_i$ are pairwise distinct, then there exists an $i$ such that $a_i = \lambda$. EDIT: the $a_i$ do not necessarily have to be distinct, but they are in $P_k(H)$.

I am then not quite sure how to proceed. There is a condition for calculating $E^N F^N v = 0$ with $P_k(H)$, which is that $Ev = 0$, but this is not necessarily true, because $Ev \in \bar{V}(\lambda + 2)$ if $v \in \bar{V}(\lambda)$. I have tried further examining the identity
$$ E^k F^k - E^{k - 1} F^k E = k (H - (k - 1)) E^{k - 1} F^{k - 1}, $$
but to no avail.

However, if we can force the evaluation of $E^N F^N v = 0 = P_k(H) v$, then we know that $\lambda$ is one of $0, 1, \dots, N - 1$. Furthermore, since the $H - a_i$ all commute with each other, we can see that $k! [\prod_{i \neq \lambda} (H - i)] (H - \lambda)v = 0$. If $(H - \lambda)v \neq 0$, then one of the $i$ must be equal to $\lambda$, which is obviously false. Thus $v$ is an ordinary eigenvector of $H$, so $H$ is diagonalizable on $\bar{V}(\lambda)$, where it can be represented as $\dim \bar{V}(\lambda)$ entries of $\lambda$ on the main diagonal.

Comment: Quick question: when you write 'some linear map' in the first paragraphs, do you mean the operator $H$? Or the Casimir $\frac{1}{4}H^2 + \frac{1}{2}(XY + YX)$? Or something else? You must have *some* information about the linear map defining the generalized eigenspace since for generic maps we cannot trust $H$ to act diagonally.

Comment: Some linear map which will be clear in the context. e.g. $\bar{V}(\lambda)$ of $H$, which is what I use here.

Comment: Ok, so it is $H$ itself? Thus diagonalizable in fact means: scalar multiple of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer that I don't have time to finish right now:

First, there exists an $M$ such that $v'=E^Mv\in \bar{V}(\lambda+2M)$ has maximal real part (i.e. $v'\in \ker E$). Now, let $N$ be such that $F^Nv'=0$ and show that $v'$ is an eigenvector for $H$.

Next, prove by induction on $k$ that $F^kv'$ is an eigenvector for $H$. When $k=1$ we have
$$HFv'=(FH+[H,F])v'=(\lambda+2(M-1))Fv'$$
and, by induction $HF^kv'=(\lambda+2(M-k))F^kv'$. In particular, $F^Mv'=F^ME^Mv$ is an eigenvector for $H$.

It is left to argue that $F^ME^Mv'$ is a nonzero multiple of $v$.

Comment: I think the last line is not true in general, where general means if $V$ is not irreducible. However, we *can* always find a finite set of vectors $v_1', \ldots v_n'$ and integers $k_1, \ldots, k_n$ such that 1) $Ev_i' = 0$ for every $i$ and 2) the vectors $F^{k_i} v_i'$ together are a basis of $\overline{V}(\lambda)$.

Comment: ...which means that your argument goes through as a sum of eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue is itself an eigenvector with that eigenvalue.

Comment: Still I find it weirdly hard to prove my assertion in the comment. It follows from the fact that every finite dimensional rep decomposes as a direct sum of irreducibles, but I forgot how to prove that. (Within each irreducible we know that every vector is of the form $F^kv'$ because every element generates the entire thing so in particular $v'$ does.)

Comment: luckily there is Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_theorem_on_complete_reducibility

Answer (score 1):

For easy readability I post as an answer what I wrote in the comments to David's answer.

- By Weyl's theorem ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_theorem_on_complete_reducibility)) we have that $V = \bigoplus V_i$ with each $V_i$ irreducible. It follows that $v = v_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus v_n$ with each $v_i$ in the corresponding $V_i$. It suffices to show that each $v_i$ is an eigenvector for $H$.
- Each $V_i$ contains an element $v'_i$ such that $Ev'_i = 0$. By your argument $v'_i$ is an eigenvector for $H$.
- By irreducibility $v_i$ is $Xv_i'$ for $X$ some complicated sum of products of $E, F$ and $H$. Since we saw in the previous bullet point that $v'$ is an eigenvector for $H$ we find (using the commutation relations) that in fact $Xv_i'$ is a scalar multiple of $F^{k_i}v_i'$ for some integer $k_i$.
- We thus can apply the argument from David's answer to see that $v_i$ is an eigenvector for $H$ as well.

Comment: While this seems correct, I think the goal of the exercise was to give one example of Weyl's reducibility theorem, namely $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, so I won't be accepting this as an answer. It does seem like the computations rely on us using the $\lambda$ with maximum real part.

Comment: Well yes, it is certainly true for that $\lambda$ but I don't see how it would help you prove the special case of the reducibility theorem. The problem lies in representation which are the direct sum of two (or more, but let's stick with two for simplicity) irreducible reps whose highest weights differ by a non-zero even integer.

Comment: I must say I really like this question!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have answered your own question. If I read correctly the only thing you need is that $E^NF^Nv = 0$ but this follows immediately from the result $F^Nv = 0$ you already have.

Comment: You also need the condition that $v\in \ker E$.

Comment: Why? $E^N 0 = 0$ no matter what role $v$ originally played in obtaining the leftmost $0$ in this equality. Or do you mean that the formula for $P_k$ derived above only holds under assumption that $Ev = 0$?

Comment: The formula only holds under the assumption that $Ev = 0$. It was computed from $[E, F^k] = ...$, and when evaluated on $v$, $F^k E v$ vanishes.

Comment: aah ok, so we need something else...

Comment: It did say in the book (Etingof) that $\lambda$ had maximal real part in part (a) and nowhere did it ever redefine $\lambda$ to be any arbitrary eigenvector, so I could have just misinterpreted the problem statement...

Comment: nevertheless, it is true that $H$ is diagonalizable on any finite dimensional representation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer without invoking Weyl's theorem or even Schur's lemma, although you might spot parts of them in the background.

I write $U(\mathfrak{g})$ for the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ to save 2 characters.

- Let $\mu_1$ be the eigenvalue of $H$ with largest real part. We have that $Ev' = 0$ for every $v' \in \overline{V}(\mu)$. Let $V_1 = U(\mathfrak{g})\overline{V}(\mu) \subset V$ be the subrepresentation of $V$ generated by $\overline{V}(\mu)$. By the reasoning in your original post and in David's answer we see that $H$ acts diagonally on $V_1$, so also on its generalized $\lambda$-eigenspace. Unfortunately this might be a relatively small subspace of the full generalized $\lambda$-eigenspace in $V$, so we move on to the next step.
- Lemma. Let $V_1$ be as above and let $v_1 \in V_1$ be any element satisfying $Ev_1 = 0$. Then $v_1 \in \overline{V_1}(\mu_1) = \overline{V}(\mu_1)$.

Proof. $v$ is a sum of $H$-eigenvectors, so if we can show that all those lie in $\overline{V}(\mu_1)$ then so does $v$. Hence it suffices to show the lemma for the case that $v$ lies at least in *some* $\overline{V}(\mu)$

Let $\omega = \frac{H^2}{4} + \frac{EF + FE}{2} \in U(\mathfrak{g})$ be the Casimir. We can check or remember from the literature that $\omega$ commutes with all elements of $U(\mathfrak{g})$. Rewriting $\omega$ in the form $H^2/4 - H/2 + EF$ we see that $\omega v_0 = \alpha v_0$ for all $v_0 \in \overline{V}(\mu_1)$, where $\alpha$ is some explicitly computable expression in $\mu_1$. (The computation is not hard, but I am scared to make sign errors so I won't do it.) Now since every $v \in V_1$ is of the form $\sum X_iv_i$ with $X_i \in U(\mathfrak{g})$ and $v_i \in \overline{V}(\mu_1)$ it follows that $\omega v = \sum \omega X_i v_i = \sum X_i \omega v_i = \alpha v$ for all $v \in V_1$. So $\omega$ acts diagonally on all of $V_1$.

Now if $v_2 \in V_1(\mu_2)$ is some $H$-eigenvector satisfying $Fv_2 = 0$ the equation $\alpha v_2 = \omega v_2 = (H^2/4 - H/2 + EF)v_2 = (H^2/4 - H/2)v_2$  shows that there are at most two possibilities for $\mu_2$.

Actually doing the computation shows that one of these possibilities is $\mu_1 + 2$ and be definition of $V_1$ we have that $\overline{V_1}(\mu_1 + 2) = \{0\}$. It follows that in reality there is only one possibility for $\mu_2$. (It can be expressed in terms of $\mu_1$ but I will just call it $\mu_2$ because I am afraid of making errors.) The upshot is that any $H$-eigenvector $v_2 \in V_1$ satisfying $Fv_2 = 0$ must live in $\overline{V}(\mu_2)$. This is close to what we want to prove, but with $F$ in the role of $E$.

Now back to vector $v$ from the lemma, i.e. a vector $v \in V_1$ satisfying $Hv = \mu v$ and $Ev = 0$. Using similar reasoning as above but exploiting the alternative expression $\omega = H^2/4 + H/2 + FE$ for the Casimir we conclude that there are at most two possible values of $\mu$. One of them is of course $\mu_1$. We want to show that this is the only possibility so we have to rule out the other one. Doing the computation we see that the other one equals $\mu_2 - 2$. Now if $\mu = \mu_2 - 2$ the vectors $F^k v$ with $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ are of the form $Fw$ with $w$ an $H$-eigenvector with eigenvalue smaller than $\mu_2$ so that $Fw \neq 0$ by the above. It would follow that $V$ is infinite dimensional, which it is not. It follows that $\mu \neq \mu_2 - 2$ and hence $\mu = \mu_1$ as we wanted to show.

- Having proven the lemma we move on with the answer.
- Let $\mu_3$ be the $H$-eigenvalue with largest real part in the quotient representation $V/V_1$. It follows that for every $[v] \in \overline{(V/V_1)}(\mu_2)$ we have that $E[v] = 0 \in V/V_1$. The brackets are added to indicate that elements of $V/V_1$ are equivalence classes of elements of $V$. In particular the statement $E[v] = 0$ means that for every representative $v \in V$ of the class $[v]$ we have that $Ev \in V_1$. Also, again using your earlier result we have that $(H - \mu_3)[v] = 0$, meaning that $(H - \mu_3)v \in V_1$ for all representatives $v$ of $[v]$. Since $Ev \in V_1$ we have that $HEv = (\mu_3 + 2)Ev$ and hence $E(H - \mu_3)v = (EH)v - \mu_3Ev = (HE -2E)v - \mu_3Ev = (H - 2)Ev - \mu_3Ev = \mu_3Ev - \mu_3Ev = 0$

It follows that $(H - \mu_3)v$ satisfies the conditions of the lemma and must hence live in $\overline{V}(\mu_1)$. But it already lived in the space $\overline{V}(\mu_3)$. By construction $\Re(\mu_3) < \Re(\mu_1)$ so $\mu_3 \neq \mu_1$. We conclude that $(H - \mu_3)v = 0$. In other words: every element in $\overline{V}(\mu_3)$ is an $H$-eigenvector.

- Now it is not hard to see from there that $H$ acts diagonally on the entire subrepresentation $U(\mathfrak{g})(\overline{V}(\mu_3))$ and hence, more interesting, in the subrepresentation $V_2 = U(\mathfrak{g})(\overline{V}(\mu_3) \oplus \overline{V}(\mu_1))$. You can see where this is going: we take the eigenvalue with largest real part of $V/V_2$, use reasoning like the above to obtain an even bigger subrepresentation $V_3$ on which $H$ acts diagonally and so on and so on, until we get to a $V_n$ that encompasses all of $V$. The only thing missing here is a version of the lemma that works for $V_i, i > 1$. We present that here, I trust that you can finish the proof from there.

Lemma: let $n \geq 1$. Let $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha n$ be a set of eigenvalues of the $H$-action on $V$ with $\Re(\alpha_1) > \ldots > \Re(\alpha_n)$ and let $V_n = U(\mathfrak{g})(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n \overline{V}(\alpha_i))$. Let $\beta$ be a complex number with $\Re(\beta) < \alpha_n$ and let $v \in V_n$ be a vector satisfying $v \in \overline{V}(\beta)$ and $Ev = 0$. Then $v = 0$.

Proof: We proceed by induction on $n$. The $(n = 1)$-case follows from the previous lemma. For $n > 1$ we consider the subrepresentations $V_{n-1} = U(\mathfrak{g})(\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n-1} \overline{V}(\alpha_i))$ and $W_n = U(\mathfrak{g})(\overline{V}(\alpha_n))$. It is clear from the definition that we can write $v = v_{n-1} + w$ with $v_{n-1} \in V_{n-1}, w \in W_n$ and both being $H$-eigenvectors at eigenvalue $\beta$, although we will not assume that this decomposition is unique. By definition of $v$ we have that $Ew = -Ev_{n-1}$. Let $\phi: V_n \to V_n/V_{n-1}$ be the quotient map. Let $W' = \phi(W_n)$. We have that $\phi(w) \in W'$ is an $H$-eigenvector with eigenvalue $\beta$ with $\Re(\beta) < \Re(\alpha_n)$ and from $Ew = -Ev_{n-1}$ we have that $E\phi(w) = 0 \in V_n/V_{n-1}$. Now we can apply the first lemma, with $V_n/V_{n-1}$ in the role of $V$ and $W'$ in the role of $V_1$ to conclude that $\phi(w) = 0$. It follows that $w \in V_{n-1}$ and hence that $v \in V_{n-1}$. But then we can apply the induction hypothesis to conclude that $v = 0$.